# How to replace sub-domain name from an url using php

Tags: php, replace

Need a help from you guys.
I have multiple sub-domains in my web site
.I am going to redirect all users to mobile version if they using a mobile device.As for example my sub-domain like

```
http://in.example.com
http://uk.example.com
http://cn.example.com
```

mobile detecting part is okay.
What i wanted to do is to **check the sub-domain name and replace it to 'm'**.
Let's say i have the following URL

```
http://uk.example.com/Gallery/index.php
```

Then the replaced URL should be like

```
http://m.example.com/Gallery/index.php
```

I will be glad if you can help me.Thanks

Comment: Aren't you breaking important language information this way? Shouldn't it be `m.in.example.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will do, check it

```
  $url = 'http://en.example.com';

    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

    $host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

    $subdomain = $host[0];
    echo $subdomain;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a function that does that:

```
public function overrideSubDomain($subDomain, $url)
{
    $info = parse_url($url);

    $array = explode('.', $info['host']);

    $withoutDomain = (array_key_exists(count($array) - 2,
            $array) ? $array[count($array) - 2] : '') . '.' . $array[count($array) - 1];

    $newSubDomain = $info['scheme'] . '://' . $subDomain . '.' . $withoutDomain;

    return $newSubDomain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
preg_replace('/\w+(?=\.\w+\.\w+)/i', 'm', 'http://uk.example.com/Gallery/index.php');
```

[image: result]